# How to use JOIN and SUM function to Calculate the total of query returned column?

Tags: sql-server, join, query, sum

I ran bellowing query;

**Query:**

```
SELECT  j.jobId,
        j.productId,
        p.productUnitPrice
FROM    JobRequiredProducts J
JOIN    Product p
  ON    p.productId = j.productId
WHERE   j.jobId = 1
ORDER BY j.jobId
```

And got bellowing result;

**Query result:**

```
jobId | productId | unitPrice 
_____________________________
  1   |     4     |   175.99
  1   |     5     |   100.00
  1   |     6     |   125.00
```

Now, I want to calculate all unitPrice to get the total. the result I expect is;

**Expecting result:**

```
jobId | productId | Total
____________________________
  1   |     4     |   175.99
  1   |     5     |   100.00
  1   |     6     |   125.00
 null |    null   |   400.99
```

Therefor bellowing is the query I tried;

**Query I tried:**

```
SELECT  j.jobId,
        j.productId,
        SUM(p.productUnitPrice) AS 'Total'
FROM    JobRequiredProducts J
JOIN    Product p
  ON    p.productId = j.productId
WHERE   j.jobId = 1 
GROUP BY j.jobId,j.productId WITH ROLLUP
```

But it didn't give me the result I expected, where I went wrong and what I gotta do to get the result I expect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use grouping set also

```
declare @JobRequiredProducts table (jobId int, productId int);
declare @Product table(productId int, productUnitPrice decimal(8,2))

insert into @JobRequiredProducts(jobId,productId)
values(1,4),(1,5),(1,6);

insert into @Product(productId, productUnitPrice)
values(4,175.99),(5 ,100.00),( 6 , 125.00)


SELECT  j.jobId,
        j.productId,
        SUM(p.productUnitPrice) AS 'Total'
FROM    @JobRequiredProducts J
JOIN    @Product p
  ON    p.productId = j.productId
WHERE   j.jobId = 1 
GROUP BY  ROLLUP ((j.jobId, j.productId));
```

with grouping sets

```
SELECT  j.jobId,
        j.productId,
        SUM(p.productUnitPrice) AS 'Total'
FROM    @JobRequiredProducts J
JOIN    @Product p
  ON    p.productId = j.productId
WHERE   j.jobId = 1 
GROUP BY  GROUPING SETS( (j.jobId, j.productId),());
```

output:

```
jobId   productId   Total
1       4           175.99
1       5           100.00
1       6           125.00
NULL    NULL        400.99
```

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2c7425990b5be5c5fa9970a51f3990b)

Comment: Please give me an Idea to this question too https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241303/how-to-calculate-the-sums-of-two-columns-when-that-two-columns-brought-by-join @Sabin Bio