# How to calculate the sums of two columns, when that two columns brought by join queries?

Tags: sql-server, join, sum

I ran two queries as shown bellow;

**query 1:** queried with JobRequiredProducts table 
and Product table to list the jobId 1 required all product and unit prices

```
SELECT  j.jobId,
        j.productId,
        p.productUnitPrice
FROM    JobRequiredProducts J
JOIN    Product p
  ON    p.productId = j.productId
WHERE   j.jobId = 1
ORDER BY j.jobId
```

**query 2:** queried with JobRequiredLabours table 
and Labour table to list the jobId 1 required labours and worked hours

```
SELECT  j.jobId,
        j.labourId,
        j.hoursOfWork   
FROM    JobRequiredLabours J
JOIN    Labour L
  ON    l.labourId = j.labourId
WHERE   j.jobId = 1 
ORDER BY j.jobId
```

And I got bellowing results:

```
Query result:

 jobId | productId | productUnitPrice
__________________________
   1   |     4     | 1500   
   1   |     5     | 800   
   1   |     6     | 1200 


 jobId | labourId | hoursOfWork
______________________________
   1   |     1     | 6    
   1   |     2     | 8
```

Now I want to calculate the total job cost by total (productUnitPrices) + (hoursOfWork * 30). And display the total cost separately. Please help me to do it. Note: 30 added to multiply because of hourly rate is 30

Comment: Thanks for you were giving me the idea, but it was so complex by the null values! I just re-posted the question clear as I can, Is there any simple way to do this? I greatly appreciate your helps @Scott Hodgin

Comment: If you want to display the total cost as a seperate column you can use a windows function (they are like group by but they show all rows in the group). What columns do you want in your final output though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are primarily looking for is a `SUM` command run on your queries where you will `GROUP BY jobId`.  That will allow you to get the `SUM` of your hours worked as well as the cost of the parts.

I can see two options that you can utilize.  Now there may be some variables I am missing but this should give you a framework to work with.

Basically what you need to do is get the `SUM` separated out which you should and then the math is fairly easy after that.  You are able to get `SUM` value by using the `GROUP BY` clause in a `SELECT` query.

**Sub Queries As "Tables"**

With this approach you create a sort of "table" which has your `SUM` pre calculated which is then added in the main `SELECT`.  (I am assuming you have some sort of a `JOB` table which is where the `jobId` column comes from).

```
SELECT J.JobID,
A.SumOfProductUnitPrice + (B.SumOfHoursWorked * 30)
FROM Job J
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  j.jobId,
        SUM(p.productUnitPrice) AS SumOfProductUnitPrice --This becomes the name of this "column" in the main SELECT statement
        FROM    JobRequiredProducts J
        JOIN    Product p
          ON    p.productId = j.productId
        GROUP BY J.JobID
    ) A
        ON A.JobID = J.JobID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  j.jobId,
        SUM(j.hoursOfWork) AS SumOfHoursWorked --This becomes the name of this "column" in the main SELECT statement
        FROM    JobRequiredLabours J
        JOIN    Labour L
          ON    l.labourId = j.labourId
        GROUP BY j.jobId
    ) B
        ON B.JobID = J.JobID
WHERE J.JobID = 1 --WHERE Command can change to return the same information for a different jobID
```

**CTE's (Common Table Expression)**

An alternative that also works is using a `CTE` (a Common Table Expression) which is almost like a `VIEW` that exists only for this query.  It allows you to pre-define a query and utilize it later in a different command.  In this particular instance we are using it to pre-generate the `SUM` so we can then use it later in a main `SELECT`.  The benefit of this is the logic of how the CTE's are created is not in the main `SELECT` which helps with readability.

```
--All CTE's need to be precided with a ";" if it is not the first statement in the batch
;
WITH ProductSum (JobID, SumOfProductUnitPrice)
AS
(
    SELECT  j.jobId,
    SUM(p.productUnitPrice) AS SumOfProductUnitPrice
    FROM    JobRequiredProducts J
    JOIN    Product p
      ON    p.productId = j.productId
    GROUP BY J.JobID
), --Comma seaparates the two CTE's that could be used in the next statement
HoursWorkSum (JobID, SumOfHoursWorked)
(
    SELECT  j.jobId,
    SUM(j.hoursOfWork) AS SumOfHoursWorked
    FROM    JobRequiredLabours J
    JOIN    Labour L
      ON    l.labourId = j.labourId
    GROUP BY j.jobId
) --No comma follows the last CTE in the chain

SELECT J.JobID,
A.SumOfProductUnitPrice + (B.SumOfHoursWorked * 30)
FROM Job J
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductSum A
        ON A.JobID = J.JobID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN HoursWorkSum B
        ON B.JobID = J.JobID
WHERE J.JobID = 1 --WHERE command can change to return the same data for a different jobId
```

These queries will get slightly more complicated, if a job requires more than one instance of a single part AND if that is held through some kind of `QUANTITY` `COLUMN` or if the Hourly Rate for a given person is not 30 every time.  But hopefully this will give you something to work with as a start.

Comment: Yes It works, Great work.. Thank you so much @Kirk Saunders